# Google cloud alert for not receiving message during an hour?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alert, google-cloud-logging

I have several Alerts in GCP for specific causes/action.
Like for myFunction:
I get an alert (slack/mail) if it fails (msg: "failed!"). The alert works for the specific text-msg "failed!"

But how to create alert if my function not started during an hour (msg: "started!")?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an alerting policy with [custom log based metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics) to look for `msg: "started!"` and in Configuration section, set the condition to: `Is absent` and select time of 1 hr